# Poisson distribution on 45 customers arriving in an 8 hour period

Tags: probability

Assume that arrivals occur according to a Poisson process with an average of seven per hour. Find the probability that 45 customers arrive in an 8 hour period.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

$\Pr(Y = 45) = \frac{8(7)^{45}}{45!}e^{-7*8}$

is this correct?

Comment: You probably need to assume the arrivals in each hour period are independent of each other. Do you know what the pdf of a sum of independent poisson random variables is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average arrival of customers per 8 hours is $$λ=8\cdot7=56$$ So the number of customer arrivals in 8 hours periods is a Poisson process $Y$ with an average $λ=56$. Therefore, the correct answer is $$P(Y=45)=e^{-56}\frac{56^{45}}{45!}$$ So, assuming that the parenthesis in the numerator is a typo (see comments), your answer is correct.

Comment: @Tyler Oh, yes he has a problem with the $8(7)^{45}$ which should be $(8\cdot7)^{45}$, right? I will edit my answer, thanks